# How can i get Parent-Child relationship values to new table when Parent and Child are stored in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with a structure as shown here:

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |

I want to display the details like this table

| Parent | Child1 | Child2 | Child 3 | Child 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |

How can I construct my SQL query? It is easy when I get parent, and child1 but it hard with child 2

When I try to use:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (CHILD2)
    SELECT CHILD 
    FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
    WHERE TABLE1.PARENT = TABLE2.CHILD1
```

I have a big database to practice this exercise, its about 225.000 entity then this scrip stuck on query execute. Sorry for my bad English, need help fast. Thank you all for read my question.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What does TABLE2 look like? How many columns are there? Do any of the relationships have a Child 5, Child 6, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can just `LEFT JOIN` the same table again and again

```sql
SELECT
  t1.Parent,
  Child1 = t1.Child,
  Child2 = t2.Child,
  Child3 = t3.Child,
  Child4 = t4.Child
FROM YourTable t1
LEFT JOIN YourTable t2 ON t2.PARENT = t1.CHILD
LEFT JOIN YourTable t3 ON t3.PARENT = t2.CHILD
LEFT JOIN YourTable t4 ON t4.PARENT = t3.CHILD;
```